# How to make my raspberry pi have a constant local ip?

Tags: pi-3, static-ip

Some Info about the pi:

```
Raspberry Pi 3 Model B
Connected over Wi-Fi and not over ethernet
Operating System: Ubuntu MATE ARM
Router: NETGEAR
```

I want the Pi to have same IP address even after rebooting or disconnecting from the router. I tried to reserve the IP on the netgear config for pi, but it seems to get a different IP then the one that's reserved. Please help!

Actually, the static IP is needed because

1. It would make connecting it over SSH easier
2. I want to make it a local server, and static IP would be better then checking the IP again and again.
3. I want to do port forwarding to the pi over a part(not port 80 though).

Comment: All of this stuff about needing a static ip is false if you use the zeroconf/avahi system that is enabled by default on Raspbian (and should be at least available on Ubuntu) and most other contemporary devices and systems (unless Windows is holding out because Apple invented it).  You just need to use *the local hostname*. But feel free to ignore this tip.

Comment: Please add a tag or tell the distribution you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique I use for setting up a static IP address is to edit the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` configuration file.  At the end of the file I add:

`ssid <My network ssid>
inform <myIPAddress>
static routers=<myRouterAddress>
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`

If you are using Ethernet, the similar would be:

`interface eth0
inform <myIPAddress>
static routers=<myRouterAddress>
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`

See also the man page here:

https://www.daemon-systems.org/man/dhcpcd.conf.5.html

Answer (score 1):

I have used the command

`sudo nano /etc/netwok/interface` and added the following

`iface enp0s25 inet static
address 10.10.8.2
netmask 255.255.0.0
gateway 10.10.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`